# Limit for fouls in Taekwondo Olympic Sparring

Tags: tae-kwon-do, sparring

At the recent Rome Grand Prix, Jade Jones won the [Women's -57 Kg final](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyTujDE3yto), with 14 points and 9 fouls made.

In a later interview she said that she was close to lose the fight by disqualification.

Is there a limit to the fouls that can be made in a combat? Reaching 10 fouls would disqualify and make her lose the match?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Article 14, bullet 7 states "When a contestant receives ten (10) “Gam-jeom”, the referee shall declare the contestant loser by referee’s punitive
declaration (PUN)"

See page 28 at the link.

[WT Competition Rules & Interpretation (Hammamet 04052018)](http://www.worldtaekwondo.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Revision-WT-Competition-Rules-Interpretation-Hammamet-040520181.pdf)

For other rules, refer to this link:

[Rules and Docs](http://www.worldtaekwondo.org/rules/)

Comment: It would help if you could add the relevant section of the rules, as well as the current date of ratification. As rules change, so may this answer. :)